# Defined variable showing NameError when it is used with .click()

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots

actually I am trying to built a bot, but getting an unusual error that my `fbb_btn` is not defined and showing `NameError` in `cmd`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

from secrets import username, password

class Webot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get('https://tinder.com')  

        sleep(2)

        fbb_btn= self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span/div[2]/button')

        fbb_btn.click()
```

> fbb_btn.click()
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   NameError: name 'fbb_btn' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your error, it seems that the xpath which you have mentioned to find the object for "fbb_btn" is not able to find the button through code.

Try to write xpath using the attributes. You can search how to write dynamic xpath using attributes to overcome this issue.

This is the reason it is giving error as 'fbb_btn' is not defined as the value is set as "None" because given xpath is not found on webpage.

Comment: but when i am giving command in cmd as                                                                                                         >>bot.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span/div[2]/button')
                                                      
 It is giving the correct output as                                               
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ff30918af38b7d26748f344cf2bbdc2b", element="0db6b379-d8cf-46b9-bc4a-ea5992882346")>

Answer (score 0):

I think you are giving wrong x-path,
there is no element with that x-path at facebook.com

there is a x-path only up-to '//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uoKd.png)/div/div'

X-path for log in button : //*[@id="u_0_4"]

X-path for sign in button : //*[@id="u_0_13"]

[image: Image that x-path do't exist]

Comment: I was trying for tinder actually, but don't want to mention it here. I know it's my mistake but giving XPath for that login button is same. Can you try for tinder once?

Comment: Please clear me , you want to clink on which button,because this xpath is not present at website ,  Please specify which button on tinder website you want to click

Comment: No problem, I have cleared the error. Actually when I was calling fbb_btn.click() I was not initializing it to a variable in cmd. So it was actually like this fbb=fbb_btn.click() now it was working fine. Thanks for your time.